# C# instantiate array value

Tags: c#, arrays

For some reason this works

```
public void TestData(ref array[,]) 
{ 
    array[0, 0] = new DataType(); 
}
```

while this doesn't work

```
public void TestData(ref array[][]) 
{ 
    array[0][0] = new DataType(); 
}
```

I've found a way around needing to use the [][] array, but would be nice to know why it doesn't seem to work the same. Do I need to instantiate at the array[0] level as well?

Comment: The first code snippet does not compile either.

Comment: The code not compiling is completely unrelated to the nature of the question, which is perfectly reasonable. Still, if what you want is a 2d array and not a jagged array, what you should use seems rather clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type[,]` is a 2-dimensional array, while `type[][]` is a 1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional arrays, sometimes called a jagged array, because the arrays are not necessarily the same length.

You can use either, depending on what makes sense. If you use a jagged array, you have to instantiate each of the arrays (the outer one and all of the inner ones). If you use a 2-D array, you just instantiate it once.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense. Moving from Lua into C#, so wasn't used to multiple types of arrays. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

"Do I need to instantiate at the array[0] level as well?" yes.

So if you want to use `T[][]` then you need to do

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         array[i] = new T[someSize];
```

So that is the basic reason why your "jagged" array isn't working. When you declare the other one it instantiates the horizontal arrays as well as the vertical one, in this case you only get the vertical one (column) and have to instantiate the rows yourself. The two aren't actually interchangeable even though working with them is fairly similar.